# Optical trapping: factor 1/2 in definition of gradient force and potential energy?

Tags: electromagnetism, potential-energy, levitation, optical-lattices

If one consider the original deduction of the gradient forces that is applied to the trapped particle we can find the following:
$$F_{grad}=\frac{1}{4} \alpha \nabla E_0^2(r),$$ where $E_0(r)$ is an amplitude of electric wave:$E(r,t)=E_0(r) \cos(\omega t)$.

See e.g.: Harada et al., Opt.Comm.124, 529, (1996)

However, on the other hand the potential energy of such a system might be deducted as: $U=(\alpha E(r,t))\:E(r,t)$ what after averaging over the time brings us to $$U=\frac{1}{2} \alpha E_0^2(r).$$
Since the transition from the potential energy to the force occurs by $\nabla$ operator, I still be confused with the missed factor of 1/2.

Can someone explain where i did a mistake?

Comment: Link to abstract page?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the dipole moment is proportional to the field whereas the expression of the potential energy of the dipole in the field  ${{E}_{p}}=-\overrightarrow{p}\cdot \overrightarrow{E}$ supposes that the dipole moment is fixed.

It is better to use  $\overrightarrow{F}=(\overrightarrow{p}\cdot \nabla )\overrightarrow{E}=\alpha (\overrightarrow{E}\cdot \overrightarrow{\nabla })\overrightarrow{E}$

Using the vector identity  $(\overrightarrow{E}\cdot \overrightarrow{\nabla })\overrightarrow{E}=\frac{1}{2}\overrightarrow{\nabla }({{\overrightarrow{E}}^{2}})-\overrightarrow{E}\wedge \underbrace{(\overrightarrow{\nabla }\wedge \overrightarrow{E})}_{\overrightarrow{0}}=\frac{1}{2}\overrightarrow{\nabla }({{\overrightarrow{E}}^{2}})$

We find  $\vec{F}=\frac{1}{2}\alpha \vec{\nabla }({{\vec{E}}^{2}})=\frac{1}{2}\vec{\nabla }(-{{E}_{p}})$

I did not take the averages into account !

Comment: Yes. Is is the definition of the polarisability ?

Comment: your $\vec{p}$ is defined in apriory as $\vec{p}=\alpha \vec{(E)}(\vec{r},t)$. Hence the potential energy will be equal to $E_p=- \overbrace{\alpha  \vec{E}(\vec{r},t)}^{\vec{p}}  \vec{E}(\vec{r},t)=\mathrm{after\:\:averaging}=\frac{1}{2}\alpha E^2_0(\vec{r})$

Now just continue with your averaging and the result that you will obtain become identical to what was written by me $\vec{F}=1/4 \alpha \nabla E^2_0(\vec{r})$

Comment: I have not taken into account your averaging. But If I unerstand you properly, it is the idea I suggested : there is a 1/2 that you must add to obtain the force from the potential energy.

Comment: What you did is shown this equality $\vec{F}=1/2 \nabla E_p$, I agree with it BUT !!! It is just refolmulated my problem.

What puzzels me is this factor 1/2, where as I would expect $\vec{F}= \nabla E_p$

Comment: In principle if the calculus were done properly, the only one explanation of this 'extra factor' of 1/2 is: we deal with non-conservative forces which does not serve the equation $F=-\nabla E_p$

Comment: The problem comes from the definition of the potential energy which supposes that we move the dipole without modifying the dipole moment. This potential energy does not take into account the energy of interaction between the charges of the dipole which is supposed constant. The dipole potential energy is the energy that must be supplied to bring, from infinity to its final position, the dipole supposed rigid, already constituted. In your case, if you imagine a small displacement of the dipole in the field, the field changes but also the dipole moment which is proportional to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89894/discussion-between-seva011-and-vincent-fraticelli).